# Node.js Return variable from event handler to parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need the function `scrape` to return the value obtained in the `page.on("request")` event handler.

```
async function scrape(url) {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        page.on("request", async(request) => {
            return "fish"
        }
        await page.goto(url)
    }
```

Currently:

```
const ans = await scrape(url)
console.log(ans)
"undefined'
```

Expected:

```
const ans = await scrape(url)
console.log(ans)
"fish"
```

Comment: why would you expect `fish`? fish is returned from the page.on callback, you don't return anything in function scrape at all - I'd recommend a Promise wrapped around `page.on` ... e.g. `return new Promise(resolve => {
        page.on("request", request => {
            resolve("fish");
        });
    });` - though, this is probably bad practice, what if page never emits 'request'!

Comment: _why_ do you expect that?

Comment: @JaromandaX 
Your recommendation worked after I tweaked it a bit. Thanks for pointing out drawbacks of this method as well. I'll write some code to handle such error cases. Thanks again!

Comment: `after I tweaked it a bit` - really? what was wrong with my code :p

Comment: Haha...not wrong per say
I just had to make the promise's resolve function asynchronous: `return new Promise(async(resolve)...` because I was running another async function within it

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's what I intended to get sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to return promise that is resolved when you see event that you are waiting

```
const matchRequest = request => request.method() === 'GET'; // your filter
async function scrape(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // not sure what your logic is, but if you don't need to cancel or modify requests/resposes you probably don't need interception
    // await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on("response", async(response) => {
        if (matchRequest(response.request())) {
           resolve(response.buffer());
        }
    }
    await page.goto(url);
  })
}

const body = await scrape('https://example.com');
```

Answer (score -1):

***Try follow like:***

```
async function scrape(url) {
    let sendRequest = []
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setRequestInterception(true)
    page.on('request', request => {
      request.continue()
      sendRequest.push('fish')
    })
    await page.goto(url)
    return sendRequest
}
```

Using [**`request.continue()`**](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestcontinueoverrides) for continues request with optional request overrides. To use this, request interception should be enabled with [**`page.setRequestInterception`**](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue). Exception is immediately thrown if the request interception is not enabled.